# Coldfusion crashing when I initiate debugging session?

Tags: debugging, server-crashes, jrun, coldfusion

I've been trying to hook up eclipse to RDS for a CF8 testing server I have in my office. Every time I try to test the connection, the CF8 application server service crashes. When I check the event logs, it turns out to be jrun crashing:

> Faulting application name: jrun.exe, version: 4.0.7.43137, time stamp: 0x47d937de
>   Faulting module name: dt_socket.dll, version: 6.0.40.12, time stamp: 0x476248fe
>   Exception code: 0xc0000409
>   Fault offset: 0x0000000000001309
>   Faulting process id: 0x27b4
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cc94069c46cfb3
>   Faulting application path: E:\ColdFusion8\runtime\bin\jrun.exe
>   Faulting module path: E:\ColdFusion8\runtime\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll

So apparently when I connect to jrun remotely, it crashes. I've searched the web 'til I'm blue in the face and still haven't found a solution. I have found other people complaining about this issue but no one seems to have any idea what is going on. Any ideas as to what could be going on or how I could get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting in a problem report to Adobe (the vendor for CF these days).